# Custom angular service injection failing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am having an issue injecting my custom service into my controller.  When I try to use the controller on the page, I receive the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=<div id="organizations-section" ng-include="'admin/organizations.html'" class="ng-scope">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%orgService
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:6:417
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:38:7
    at Object.d [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:38:81
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:283)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:432)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:37:184)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js:36:315)
```

Here is my JavaScript file that defines the application, service and controller:

### admin/admin.js

```
adminApp = angular.module("admin", []);

adminApp.service("orgService", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http){

}]);

adminApp.controller("OrganizationController", ["$scope", "orgService", function($scope, orgService){

}]);
```

### admin.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="admin">
    <div id="organizations-section" ng-include="'admin/organizations.html'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### organizations.html

```
<div ng-controller="OrganizationController as orgCtrl">
  <h2>Organizations</h2>
</div>
```

I should note that this is a Rails 4.2 application.  I've tried to strip out as much code as necessary to simplify this, and I'm still seeing the problem.  If I remove `orgService` from the Controller definition, it's fine.  But I can't seem to get that one to work.  I've looked at other examples of service definitions, and just don't see the issue.

Comment: You are injecting $scope into your service. Get rid of that. You can't do that.

Comment: @ribsies Thank you.  That was the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is issue with your service declaration

> You can't inject $scope into services, there is no such thing as a
>   Singleton $scope.

If you want then you can do add inject `$rootScope`. But usually `service` is used for placing common methods in it like you can make ajax call from it and then return the appropriate data or promise to callee method.

**CODE**

```
adminApp = angular.module("admin", []);

adminApp.service("orgService", ["$http", 
   function($http){

   }
]);

adminApp.controller("OrganizationController", ["$scope", "orgService", 
    function($scope, orgService){
    }
]);
```

Hope this could help you Thanks.

Comment: This fixed it.  I removed `$scope` from the `orgService` definition and no more errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When using dependency injection in your controller you are declaring `$scope` and `orgService` as dependencies, but your function has three parameters including `notifyService`.

I think you need to declare `notifyService` in the dependecies as well:

```
adminApp.controller('OrganizationController', ['$scope', 'orgService', 'notifyService',
  function($scope, orgService, notifyService){

}]);
```

Make sure, that the service `notifyService` exists or remove it from the dependencies of `OrganizationController`.

Comment: Good catch.  That's left over from things I removed trying to strip this code down.  Unfortunately, the error still persists.

Comment: From [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) i just read this: 

// a scope object cannot be injected into a service.

what do you want to achieve with the $scope in the service?

Comment: Originally, I was using `$scope` to handle callbacks from the http service.  I probably (incorrectly) copied this behavior from some other controllers I had written.

TL;DR: RTFM.